# Ruby on Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou tendo problemas para setar a pagina home como root na minha aplicação.

no arquivo `config/routes.rb` já fiz vários tentativas como:

```
root :to => 'static_pages#home'
```

e

```
root   'static_pages#home'
```

Mas nenhuma funciona, estou trabalhando com ela dessa forma:

```
get 'home' => 'static_pages#home'
```

Qual sintaxe é a correta para por como root?

Comment: Você conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a documentação [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) para criar uma [rota para o `root`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) basta fazer igual ao seu segundo exemplo.

Pode ser `root to: 'static_pages#home'` ou `root 'static_pages#home'`.

Lembrando que neste exemplo `static_pages` seria seu ***controller*** e `home` sua ***action***.

**Obs:** Para versões antigas do `Ruby on Rails` é recomendado apagar o seu arquivo "`/public/index.html`".